issues with previewing animations when i have done one and want to play another seperately
I am new blender and was trying to learn animations. I tried a man sliding as my first and a ball moving as my second. When I tried the first animation, it worked fine . But when I tried the second , the first and the second collided. How do i remove the first from playing with the second?

You don't, either you want them simultaneous or you want them "in different frame ranges"
